# Normal file i/o operations in asterisk

Tags: file-io, asterisk

I am using asterisk to implement a voice server. I have the following two questions:

1. I want to be able to read/write files to impart some additional functionality. Is there a way to do so in asterisk? I noticed that normal functions such as cout etc. for writing output is suppressed.
2. Is there a way to debug applications written in asterisk? I mean something like a gdb for asterisk?

Any help on the above questions is most welcome.
Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that in your comment on Michael's answer, you said you were using C / C++.

You can definitely do file I/O in Asterisk using C or C++ (or any language really). Asterisk supports four primary types of applications:

Dial Plan: The default Asterisk scripting language. Any code that's in `extensions.conf` is dial plan. You can use this language to control inbound calls, and do stuff. For file I/O, dial plan provides a `System` command, as well as an `AGI` command which both allow you to run other software (like a bash script, a C binary, anything really). Then in your bash script, C program, etc., you can just do normal file I/O as if you were running the program on the command line yourself. EX:

```
[some_context]
exten => s,1,System(/bin/echo "hello, world" >> /tmp/test.txt)
exten => s,n,Return()

[launch_an_agi]
exten => s,1,AGI(/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/my_c_program,optional_cmd_line_arguments,to,pass)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

AGI: The Asterisk AGI (launched from dial plan code) lets you run external programs (a C program or whatever), and passes your C program some Asterisk variables about the call which is currently being processed, that your program can use. You can use your normal coding tools here to do any file I/O you want, eg:

```
/* some_c_agi_program */
include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w");
    (void)fprintf(f, "MY FILE IO WORKS! THANKS STACKOVERFLOW!\n");
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

AMI: The AMI is a network API that Asterisk provides. You can use this to write programs that run on another server, that can create, control, and show you the status of calls on an Asterisk server. The idea is that you connect over a TCP socket to the asterisk server in your program, then send commands and read back the responses. I'm not going to show an example, because it would be a huge program in C. But you get the idea.

- More information on dial plan: http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk%20config%20extensions.conf
- More information on AGI: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI
- More information on AMI: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

Now, onto debugging!

Depending on the type of application you're writing, there are various ways to debug. If you're familiar with the concept of unit testing, you can write unit tests, and make sure that they are ran for any of the methods I'm about to describe. For general purpose debugging (if you're writing an AGI or AMI program), your normal C debugger (GDB) can be used.

Comment: thanks for the reply! what options/flags do i need to supply gdb with? Also, the file i/o thing resolved to a permissions problem. Enabling read permissions for all enabled me to open files and read them like C from within the C code i wrote. Additionally, the C code was for functions that would be called from within the dialplan.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but does it need to be any more complex than Asterisk's own built in [FILE](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_FILE) function?

### Examples:

reads the entire content of the file.

```
Set(foo=${FILE(/tmp/test.txt)})
```

reads the 3rd line of the file.

```
Set(foo=${FILE(/tmp/test.txt,3,1,l)})
```

Replace the last line of the file with "cat"

```
Set(FILE(/tmp/foo.txt,-1,,l)=cat)
```

Append "dog" to the file with a newline

```
Set(FILE(/tmp/foo.txt,,,al)=dog)
```

---

Dialplan example:

```
exten => 800,n,Set(FILE(/tmp/cid.txt,,,al)=${CALLERID(num)})
```

Comment: Many simple things can also be achieved with System("shell command"), which is what I found easiest for copying various wav files around.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you use AGI? Of course with AGI you can read/write files.
2. You can use `-vvvvvvv` command line option to make asterisk verbose. More `v` make asterisk more verbose. For me it was enough to debug dialplans. If I wanted to debug AGI, then I used logging to some log file, or for simplier tasks I used fake agi_lib (good for unit tests where true AGI is not available).

Comment: I have some C code where I add the functionality described above. I want to read the file in real time (for which I have a C++ class and C wrapper) and make alterations to the frame data on the basis of what is read. So, I want to know if there is a C/C++ like file i/o method for this. Also, do you think I should edit my question and include this in case it is not clear?